# How composer determines stability of a module?

Tags: php, composer-php, version, versioning, stability

When I do

```
composer install mmerian/doctrine-timestamp
```

`composer` says

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package mmerian/doctrine-timestamp at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the pa
  ckage spelling or your minimum-stability
```

But with this

```
composer install mmerian/doctrine-timestamp=dev-master
```

it works out. How `composer` determines stability of a package? Can I make a version alpha by naming it `alpha-master`?

**UPD** My question differs slightly from [the one suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650543/how-to-mark-code-as-stable-using-composer). It's not only about marking code as stable. Not sure how to phrase my question better, but see the answer I expected:

`composer` takes versions of a package from tags and branches. And most of the time it infers versions (unless specified explicitly, which is not recommended).

Versions taken from branches [get](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#branches) `stable` stability. The ones taken from [tags](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#tags) get stability based on their suffix.

As such, when running `composer install mmerian/doctrine-timestamp` with `minimum-stability` `stable` (which is the default), it can't find a stable version, since the only version as of yet is `dev-master`. And fails.

When running `composer install mmerian/doctrine-timestamp=dev-master`, the package [implicitly gets](https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html) (which I can't see in the docs) `@dev` [stability flag](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links), which basically means `minimum-stability = dev` for this particular package. Therefore it succeeds.

Comment: It's whatever the package creator/maintainer says it is. It could be rock-solid and marked as `dev-master` or similar, or it could be flaky and dangerous and marked as stable.

Comment: [Where exactly](https://github.com/mmerian/doctrine-timestamp/blob/master/composer.json) developer says it's `dev-master`? What are the rules governing assigning stability?

Comment: See the question linked above. In particular, see [this link from the top answer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#tags).