# I can't flag my composer development as stable

Tags: composer-php

I'm developing [my first composer package as a test](https://github.com/MarcBrillault/namedColors), and everything is ok, except that I didn't manage to flag my code as stable.

When requiring my code, if my composer.json file does not have a "minimim-stability": "dev", I've got this error message :

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

I've already read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650543/how-to-mark-code-as-stable-using-composer), and I created a 1.0.0 Tag, but it does not change anything.

Could someone explain what I've missed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, its works now, maybe I was too impatient.