# Composer can't install

Tags: php, composer-php, package

I am writing a php library and i [published it on packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/merajsiddiqui/ibm-watson) but am unable to download it using composer

```
composer require merajsiddiqui/ibm-watson
```

But it throws error

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
  Could not find package merajsiddiqui/ibm-watson at any version for your min  
  imum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stabili  
  ty
```

Here is my repository: https://github.com/merajsiddiqui/ibm-watson

I would be thankful if you can guide me to successfully publishing so any one can download this library.

Comment: I can't see any stable (aka versioned) release, just the master branch. Your local Composer setup is probably set to only install stable versions.

Comment: how to add that and whats the importance of that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your package is still in "dev" mode.

[Add a tag to your repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223354/2119863), publish the tagged (versioned) repo.

Or add this to your composer.json:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

for example:

```
# composer.json
{
    "name": "ProjectUsingMyIBMWatsonPackage",
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

then run:

```
 $ composer require merajsiddiqui/ibm-watson
 Using version dev-master for merajsiddiqui/ibm-watson 
 (...)
   - Installing merajsiddiqui/ibm-watson (dev-master f7b808d) Cloning f7b808dd97 from cache
```

Comment: in which composer i have to add the minimum stability .. as i added in ibm-watson repo and tried to install it shows same error do i have to add in the compose.json where i am trying to download it ..?

Comment: In the project you want to use your library in.

Comment: Downgrading minimum-stability may work for you in this one case, but is a bad idea; just tag your versions.

Comment: What Narf said ;)

Comment: At least, if you really need to use the development version of a particular package, please do not lower the `minimum-stability` flag for all your dependencies, but rather explicitly require the dev version of this particular package: `composer require merajsiddiqui/ibm-watson:dev-master`

Answer (score 1):

`minimum-stability: stable` means that development versions of the library cannot be installed - that's the default `minimum-stability` setting. And for good reasons - a "dev" version changes constantly, and is thus unreliable.

You need to release an actual (non-RC, non-alpha, non-beta) version of your library for it to be considered "stable".

With Git, that means using `git tag`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

https://packagist.org/

and create a package from your repo. Then it's available. Otherwise you have to add your repo in your composer configuration manually.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md

The other problem is that your package is not marked es "stable" then your can't add them when your `minimum stability` is `stable`. So go to your `composer.json` and set them to stable.

[How to mark code as stable using Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650543/how-to-mark-code-as-stable-using-composer)

Comment: i have succfully added but unable to download https://packagist.org/packages/merajsiddiqui/ibm-watson

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650543/how-to-mark-code-as-stable-using-composer

Answer (score 0):

Add `"minimum-stability": "dev"` in your composer json file or release version of your library.