# Could not find package with stability stable

Tags: composer-php

Hi I'm trying to create a composer package and can't seem to figure out how to mark it as stable. I've tried tagging it as v1.x, setting these in composer.json:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

https://github.com/monsterlane/lumen-console-tests

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mark code as stable using Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650543/how-to-mark-code-as-stable-using-composer)

Comment: I saw that post and read it but I'm not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: In that linked post and all the Google searches I've done it sounds like all I should have to do is tag something >= 1.0.0 and create a release in Github. I've done both, tried with and without the min-stability+prefer-stable lines in composer.json.

When I run composer `create-project monsterlane/lumen-console-test` I get:

    [InvalidArgumentException]
    Could not find package monsterlane/lumen-console-test with stability stable.

Comment: I can't create a project from it or require it in another project. I'm doing everything in here and it doesn't work? https://medium.com/@mazraara/create-a-composer-package-and-publish-3683596dec45

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/monsterlane/lumen-console-test

If a link to that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Gwah my version of composer was to old so the package wasn't visible.